# Google Sheets - decrease value by fixed amount on specified date each month

Tags: google-sheets

As above, I have created a net worth tracker and I have a desire to have it update on its own based on fixed payment amounts I make each month vs a certain value.

For example, on cell D8 i have the value of my mortgage (let's say its negative 100,000). Every month on the 23rd of each month I want D8 to decrease (technically increase as it is a negative number but you know my meaning) negative 100 000 by 500 I.e. on the 22nd it shows as 100,000 then on the 23rd it will change to 99,500. The following month after the next 23rd it will decrease to 99,000 and so on.

I have looked across a few different examples but have only been able to find examples that have a fixed duration, where here I want it to just go on indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want/need is a formula consisting of two things:

1. Calculate the time/days since a certain start date (in for example months, or the amount of "23rd day of the month"s that have passed). This Google formula will provide you with the current date/time: https://www.liveflow.io/product-guides/google-sheets-today-formula
2. Multiply by your paydown amount and add to the initial mortgage amount (it was a negative number to you, you said). After the mortgage is fully paid, the amount (positive number, once it was paid in full) will increase further indefinitely (given you keep the Sheet around and use it for a long time).

If I understood the TODAY() formula correctly, your Sheet will always show the correct "mortgage to be paid" amount based on the exact day you open the Sheet.

Comment: This is the right idea but the actual practicality of writing the formula is unfortunately beyond me! I am new to Google sheets so still at the point where my ambitions are beyond my ability!

Comment: @Sulphix: instead of trying to come up with a huge, single formula at once, try dividing it into smaller calculations in separate cells. You can do it! This will allow you to validate your intermediate answers as well.